# Public Folder in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

The public application folder in the Skeleton Application is a folder that serves to support the front controller, or does the framework use it in any way?

Anyway, if I switch the public folder name in Skeleton Application, does not the framework continue to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public/index.php` is entry point for all requests, that is configured on a **web server and .htaccess**.

in index.php you are doing 2 important things:

1. Load all the code you have in the app

   ```
   // Composer autoloading
   include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
   ```
2. Instancing the application and run it

   ```
   // Run the application!
   Application::init($appConfig)->run();
   ```

Everything else and front controller, takes place within the framework and your application.

Anyway, you can change folder name! Just be sure you've **configured everything on the web server side**.